# Augmented Assignment variable value

Tags: python, variables

Sorry for a question that might sound dumb, but in Python, is there a way to easily add 1 to a variable value, rather than doing

```
   var_one = 1
   var_one = var_one + 1
```

all the time?

Comment: apart from saarrrr's suggestion, no. There's no `var_one++` like operator like in c++.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one on for size:

```
var_one += 1
```

Comment: That works perfectly for what I was using it for.